# Expo with Android Studio error : no stack

Tags: react-native

I got an error while launch my expo project on Android Studio ADV ,
I got the error as follow:
[image]

Anyone can help pleaseeee !! Thank you so much !!

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I think this is a related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480444/unexpected-token-no-stack-android-emulator-expo

Comment: hi @patataskr , I am not using expo for a long time ,so I do not remenber if I have solved it or not :p ... However,thank you so much for your menthod too :D